# Analyze the website

Tags: usability, user-research, ux-field, emotion, trust

I have no idea how to analyze a website if PET design principles are followed or not for a particular website. I have started practicing UX though I was a front end developer. Dont have clue if this website has followed the PET design principles or not.
www.airbnb.com

Thanks-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently conducting and learning about Human-Centered Design. PET stands for :

- Persuasion
- Emotion
- Trust

All of these element could be understood by following Persuasion Design that contains 6 Principles ( reciprocity, scarcity, authority ,consistency, liking, consensus ). If you look at Airbnb.com, you would notice that they are using at least one of those 6 strategies.

-To increase the program’s user signups and bookings by over 300% per day.[Airbnb used the principle of liking to reengineer their “underutilized and underperforming”.](http://unbounce.com/landing-pages/six-principles-of-persuasion-landing-pages/)

Additionally, Persuasion is applied in many domains such as health, behavior change, businesses,etc. I would recommend you to watch and read Dr.Bj Fog books and videos. You will learn how to design application that contains persuasive techniques.This is more related to psychology, so there are many techniques that work and some don't.

I hope this is useful and if you have more questions. Please ask :).

Comment: Good use of Cialdini's principles!

Comment: Yes, this. Familiarize yourself with Robert Cialdini's work. That'll give you a good starting point: https://www.youtube.com/user/influenceatwork

Comment: To be honest I didn't get anything from this answer and the comments confused me even more!. Then again, the question couldn't be more broad, so maybe it's just that I'm not interpreting the same thing

Comment: @Devi Hmm, it's okay, maybe you just need to google "Robert Cialdini " or "Persuasion design". :) Have a nice day!

Comment: @SeragAlzentani, thank you for your advice, I'll ask my wife that worked for a few years with Cialdini, maybe she can tell me who he is. And still your smatass comment doesn't help me to understand how this answers the question (although, as I admitted, I have no idea what the OP is asking)

Comment: @Devin you are welcome. I am not referring to him personally, I am only advising you to read about his persuasion theory that has been used in several businesses such as '' Restaurant'' when the waiter/waitress gives you a gift '' mint-sweet'' at the same time they give you the bill, 1 mint typically increases the amount of the tips to about 3%. This is called Reciprocity, the art of receiving kindness and paying back with kindness ;). So you could apply the same thing on any website/app application as they say '' build something that people care about people will take care of you'' :).